# Help symplifyinf this pre-calculus queston please

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{ab}{a^2+ab+b^2}+\left(\frac{ac-ad-bc+bd}{ac-ad+bc-bd}\cdot\frac{a^3+b^3}{a^3-b^3}\right)$$

I am stuck trying to simplify this expression, I need help please.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some un-foiling can make this a lot simpler. Note that$ac-ad-bc+bd = (a-b)(c-d)$ and $ac-ad+bc-bd =(a+b)(c-d)$, and $a^3+b^3 =(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$, and lastly $a^3-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$. Also, the portion of your equation to the right of your division sign can be flipped over and turned into multiplication. Thus you will get $$\frac{ab}{a^2+ab+b^2}+\frac{(a-b)(c-d)}{(a+b)(c-d)} \cdot \frac{(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)}{(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)}$$ Now you can cancel all the $(a-b),(a+b)$ and $(c-d)$ terms. You will be left with  $$\frac{ab}{a^2+ab+b^2}+\frac{(a^2-ab+b^2)}{(a^2+ab+b^2)}$$ Now your two fractions have the same denominator so you can add everything in the numerators. Your final result should be $$\frac{(a^2+b^2)}{(a^2+ab+b^2)}$$ I think that is as far as you can simplify for now.